# Spring-boot 3.1.0+ / Hibernate 6.2+ - Unable to generate the COUNT query from JPQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

My project is currently working properly in spring-boot version 3.0.6 with Hibernate 6.1.7.

Since the release of spring-boot 3.1, which upgrade Hibernate to 6.2.2 (issue still present with spring-boot 3.2 and hibernate 6.3.1), the application is failing at start up because hibernate don't generate some COUNT request correctly from the JPQL.

We use postgresQL 15

I get the following error :

```
org.hibernate.query.SyntaxException: At 1:28 and token 'as', no viable alternative at input 'SELECT count(DISTINCT f.id *as fooId, .....]
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator$1.syntaxError(StandardHqlTranslator.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
```

The COUNT query is not specified and is automatically generated by hibernate for the following method :

```
@Query("""
SELECT DISTINCT
    qr.id as fooId,
    MAX(c.name) as fooGroupName,
    MAX(d.lastUpdatedDate) as fooDate,
    MAX(l.startDepartureDate) as fooSecondDate,
    MAX(d.destination.code) as destination,
    MAX(d.origin.code) as origin,
    f.type as fooType,
    f.status as fooStatus
FROM FooEntity f
    JOIN f.fooUser u
    JOIN f.fooDetails d
    JOIN f.fooCategory c
    JOIN d.fooLines l
    JOIN f.userCompany uc
WHERE
    d.status IN (:fooDetailStatuses)
    AND f.status IN (:fooStatuses)
    AND (:source = 'ALL' OR f.source = :source)
    AND (:fromDate IS NULL OR cast(l.fromDate as String) >= :fromDate)
    AND (:toDate IS NULL OR cast(l.toDate as String) <= :toDate)
    AND (:#{#origins.size} = 0 OR d.origin.code IN :origins)
    AND (:#{#destinations.size} = 0 OR d.destination.code IN :destinations)
    AND (:#{#brands.size} = 0 OR d.brands.code IN :brands)
    AND c.level = 1
    AND (:#{#categories.size} = 0 OR c.id IN :categories)
GROUP BY f.id, f.type, f.status
""")
    Page<Map<String, Object>> findPaginatedId(Pageable pageable, String source, 
                                          @Param("fooDetailStatuses") List<FooDetailStatus> fooDetailStatuses,
                                          @Param("fooStatuses") List<FooStatus> fooStatuses,
                                          String fromDate, String toDate, List<String> origins, List<String> destinations, List<String> brands, List<Integer> categories);
```

I didn't find anything on the hibernate documentation that would indicate that my request is not valid.

Comment: Can you please reduce that to a [mcve]?